# Adobe Creative SDK Image Editor cancelled next month

Tags: adobecreativesdk

According to [here](https://blog.creativesdk.com/):

> Developer support for the Image Editor UI, Color UI, Market Browser, and Labs components will be discontinued after the November 2017 release and the Creative SDK team will no longer be able to answer any integration-related questions or address any crashes or bugs that you may come across for these components. We encourage you to reach out to our Help Center prior to the November 2017 release.

and

> The Image Editor UI, Color UI, Market Browser, and Labs components will no longer be available to integrate in new applications (iOS, Android, web).

What are everyone's plans for replacing Image Editor?  Is there anything equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [Photo Editor Sdk](https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/). I 've just contacted them about the pricing, and I'm waiting for a reply. Let's see how it goes.

Comment: Interesting!  And there appears to be a free version on github [here](https://github.com/imgly/imgly-sdk-html5).  And another one [here](https://github.com/imgly/pesdk-html5-build).

Comment: Just a followup. I've found some other guys that are giving their SDK for free. Give them a try here: https://www.dsphotoeditor.com/

Comment: However, that is for native OS development.  I am still looking for a solution for HTML5 / Cordova development.

Comment: Ah, in html5 you can use fotor.com. They're going to make their Sdk available to integrate as a developer.